# Pokemon search engine

Tags: python, performance, python-2.x, regex, pokemon

I am making a simple function to find and match any *possibilities* what Pokémon the user wants. This is accomplished by taking in the input (what the user thinks the Pokémon is named) and compare its spelling with preset Pokémon names (letter by letter searching). With each successful match, the Pokémon's score (determined by its value in the dictionary) will go up by one. Only the top seven Pokémon are returned.

The function:

```
import re
import operator

# Dictionary of Pokemon
list_of_chars = {"Bulbasaur": 0, "Ivysaur": 0, "Venusaur": 0, "Squirtle": 0, "Wartotle": 0, "Blastoise": 0,
                 "Charmander": 0, "Charmeleon": 0, "Charizard": 0, "Zapdos": 0, "Articuno": 0, "Moltres": 0, "Mew": 0,
                 "Mewtwo": 0}
list_of_keys = []

# Allow the list to actually contain the keys
for key in list_of_chars:
    list_of_keys.append(str(key))


def indiv_search(entry):
    certain_list = []
    # Loop through the possible Pokemon
    for i in range(0, len(list_of_keys)):
        # Loop through each *letter* of the entry
        for b in range(0, len(entry)):
            try:
                # Match each letter of entry with the letter of the Pokemon
                m = re.search(str(entry[b]), list_of_keys[i][b], re.IGNORECASE)
            except IndexError:
                continue
            if m is not None:
                # Match is successful 
                list_of_chars[list_of_keys[i]] += 1
            elif m is None:
                # Match is not successful
                continue
    # "Sort" dictionary by score values
    sorted_x = sorted(list_of_chars.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1))
    # Take only top seven choices
    while len(sorted_x) > 7:
        del sorted_x[0]
    for i in range(6, -1, -1):
        certain_list.append(sorted_x[i][0])
    # Return results
    return "Possible Choices: " + ", ".join(certain_list)

while True:
    # Take input, keep in string format
    poke_name = str(raw_input("Pokemon's Name: "))
    if poke_name == "QUIT":
        break
    else:
        # Print results
        print indiv_search(poke_name)
        # Reset all values in dictionary
        for i in range(0, len(list_of_chars)):
            list_of_chars[list_of_keys[i]] = 0
```

Example output:

> ```
> Pokemon's Name: Char  
> Possible Choices: Charmander, Charizard, Charmeleon, Blastoise, Articuno, Venusaur, Zapdos
> ```

Note that the first line contains the `raw_input()` prompt and the input (separated by a space due to the prompt purposely having a space at the end to improve readability). The second line has the results of the function.

I have a few questions:

- Is the code Pythonic?
- What can be improved to uphold PEP rules?
- What can be done to improve the efficiency and if possible, accuracy of the code?

Comment: Have you seen [`difflib`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/difflib.html)?

Comment: @zondo Interesting. It looks cool but maybe a bit hard to implement for now. The `get_close_matches()` might be useful though

Comment: Am I misunderstanding, or are you using `re.search` where you could use `in`?

Comment: What do you mean by `in`? Like `a in b`?

Comment: Yes.  Why use `re.search(x, y, re.IGNORE_CASE)` instead of `x.lower() in y.lower()`?

Comment: Why does it think I mean Articuno when I ask for Char? That's not even remotely related.

Comment: @Mast: Because there are only four names that match.  The other three don't match, but the requirement is seven names.

Comment: @zondo An odd requirement if you ask me. Author, are you sure the specification doesn't ask for 'up to seven' instead of 'always seven'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are much simpler ways to do this.    The easy way is to use `difflib.get_close_matches()` which is very similar to what you are creating.  If you insist on making your own, there are still simpler ways.

---

First of all, why regex?  You don't have patterns to match.  You have simple equality tests.  The only thing that makes it different from `a in b` is `re. IGNORE_CASE`.  Simply fixed, do `a.lower() in b.lower()`.  In this case, however, you actually mean `a.lower() == b.lower()`.

---

Iterating through two sequences in parallel is a common enough task that Python made it easy with `zip()`.  Instead of

```
for i in range(len(a))):
```

with `a[i]` and `b[i]`, you can use

```
for a_item, b_item in zip(a, b):
```

Conveniently, it stops at the end of the shortest iterable (not in Python 3).

---

Your method of limiting the number of matches returned is not ideal. Instead of deleting the ones you don't want, keep only the ones that you do. That is done simply with a slice.

---

In Python, the `bool` class (for True and False) inherits from the `int` class. Therefore, you can do arithmetic with booleans.  True is 1, and False is 0. With that knowledge and the earlier improvements, we get something much simpler:

```
def diff_score(iter_a, iter_b):
    return sum(a == b for a, b in zip(iter_a.lower(), iter_b.lower()))

def best_matches(guess, names, num_matches):
    matches = sorted(names, key=lambda x: diff_score(x, guess), reverse=True)
    return  matches[:num_matches]
```